# .net framework single authorize in multiple difference policy and policy both are same than get access of the method

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.8

there are both policy same than get the access of a method or controller asp.net framework 4.8
authorize in policy and policy both are match the give in claim than get the access

I am try to solve this Problem but can't solve this problem

Comment: Could you please share more details about your issue? It would be great if you could share your minumul reproducible sample in order to assist you better.